# How should the scene "Please Hold" from "Sea to Unsalty Sea" be completed?

Tags: the-grand-tour-game

On the scene "Please Hold" from the Episode 11 of the Season 3, you need to drive the Bentley Continental GT as Hammond after taking 3 pints of water. The problem is that you can't:

- Be at more than 20 MPH during the corners (otherwise Hammond is going to pee himself)
- Driving pretty slowly to make it safely to the end (there is a time limit)
- Drifting in the corner (+5 "SLOSH")

Considering the restrictions of the scene, how it should be completed? (Sadly I can't take "The Clarkson Route")